# Efficiently testing primacy for large numbers

Tags: performance

I have a book that mentions that if instead of testing `testnum <= innum; innum % testnum == 0` you can do `testnum * testnum <= innum`

Is this exactly twice as efficient?

**EDIT**
I doubt anyone really cares, but I did benchmark this.
The `test*test <= num` took 8.9 seconds for 100000000000000000 without any compiler optimization and 7.9s with `-Ofast`

The other one was let to run for 1.5minutes and was still painfully calculating, so I put it out of its misery.

Comment: Why don't you benchmark it?

Comment: Because I don't know the first thing about benchmarking

Comment: It sounds like you've already answered your own question. If the other one was still calculating after 1.5 minutes, then the first one is significantly more than twice as efficient.

Comment: Hence the edit in case anyone else has a similar question, they have the answer.

Comment: Does the book mention what you are trying to do? Those two statements evaluate differently. Say you have `testnum = 3` and `innum = 6`, the first statement will evaluate `true` and the second `false`. What are these testing?

Comment: It's finding all the divisors of a number and if the only divisor is 1 and that number, it is prime.

I guess it isn't specific to primes, but the idea of only testing the first half (any divisors after `.5*num` will just be the first set in reverse) was neat to me.

Comment: So we are talking about a primality test? Yes, you need only check all the (prime) numbers up to the square root of the number to be tested. This is much better than twice as fast. You are comparing `N` to `sqrt(N)`, so it's exactly `sqrt(N)` times as fast. For `100000000000000000`, that's about 316 million times faster.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that now. What with 90s vs 8s. I just did `100000000000000000` and it looks to be about 316 _million_ times faster, according to wolfram|alpha.