# Refusing to use <= in C

Tags: c, syntax, convention

I have this habit in C (and many other languages) where rather than `foo <= bar` I will do `foo < bar + 1` and no idea where this even came from...

Is this bad, per se, or just nonstandard? I mean from the context of coding and later modifying the code...I assume any good compiler compiles both of them the same.

Comment: This is broken in all kinds of ways, especially with edge cases, signed/unsigned, and (obviously) with floating point.

Comment: Might behave differently with overloaded operators?

Comment: Does anyone else have to work on that code? Do them a favor and don't do that.

Comment: Nobody else seems to have mentioned it, so I will - it's also slower. Assuming that bar isn't a constant, the program will have to retrieve the value of bar, add one to it and then check to see if foo is less than this sum. The less-than-or-equal operator, on the other hand, has a single CPU instruction that can perform the check. It also saves on register use, which can again help program speed, since an extra register is now available. Whether or not you program anything where this matters or not is another matter. But the fact remains - it's slower.

Comment: Thanks. Even though I don't program aanything where it matters, speed sure is fun. See my other recent question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620593/efficiently-testing-primacy-for-large-numbers  ...it's also about speed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is bad for multiple reasons:

- Does not work for floating point numbers
- Does not work for signed numbers (`-2.5 <= -3` is false, but `-2.5 < -3 + 1` is true)
- Makes your code difficult to understand
- Increases the chances that you'll (needlessly) create an overflow error

It's bad **and** nonstandard. There's really no reason to continue reinforcing the habit - you're just shooting yourself in the foot for later in your coding career.

Comment: It's going to be hard to break. I remember reading in some book once that it helps prevent errors with how many iterations of loops take place.

Comment: Really quick popped through around 100 files and fixed it. Wish I knew some regex to do it...

Comment: You could potentially try the regex `< ?-?[0-9]+ ?\+ ?1`. That will look for, in order: a `<`, an optional space, an optional `-`, any nonzero number of digits, an optional space, a `+`, an optional space, and a `1`.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's less clear, personally. Also it could be bad if foo and bar are not integers; for example the two will mean something different if foo= -7 and bar = -7.5.

Comment: After reading this and the comments on my post it does make sense that this is such an odd thing to do, but I don't know why I even started doing it.

you suggest to use regular `>=` `<=` then instead of my convoluted method?

Comment: yes, otherwise they wouldn't exist

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment:

> it helps prevent errors with how many iterations of loops take place

You're most likely referring to looping in these two ways:

Method I:

`for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){ // }` which would go between 0 and length-1.
Versus:

Method II:

`for(int i = 0; i <= length-1; i++){ //}` which also goes between 0 and length-1.

In these particular cases, either will work, but as Derek Redfern outlined in his answer above, don't make your code any more complicated than it should be.

Answer (score 1):

It is very broken, especially when you do

```
int foo = <whatever>;
int bar = INT_MAX;
if (foo < bar + 1) {
  /* guaranteed to never be called */
}
```

Also, it is likely to break if you "adjust" it in the other way, like so

```
int foo = INT_MIN;
int bar = <whatever>;
if (foo - 1 < bar ) {
  /* again guaranteed never to be called */
}
```

In short, far better to check for equal and greater (or equal and less than) than to create code that adjusts a value during the comparison.